# Query and comparing 2 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

i have a table that is stored all records of products, and than i have other table that stores all records that i bought in the table products.

In one of my pages i list all my products, but i will to list only the products that were not bought from the user. How can i query the listing of products to only show products that i didnt bought? How can i make this comparation or intersection in eloquent?

In my case the producst are information from users, or more specifically answers from Inquiries, the identifyer of the user is by email, i query by group of emails, and the email is unique for each survey.

ex:

```
 $survey = $survey->answers->groupBy('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any details of the tables, i will make some assumptions:

The product table has an id coloumn, the second table has some form of product id, to see what has been bought.

You should take a look at this:

```
DB::table('bought_stuff')->whereNotIn('email', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

you can read about it here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses under "whereNotIn".

It is a little difficult for me to answer, as i'm not completely sure about what you mean in the last part..